# Set singular/plural depending on the number of comments in Timber

Tags: timber

I'm using the following timber code:

```
{{post.comment_count}} reply on "{{post.title}}"
```

to output how many comments a post does have. Is there a way to output "reply" if there is only one comment and "replies" if there are more than one?

I'm searching for a Timber/Twig way, of course I can do it with Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Found it:

```
{{post.comment_count}} {{ _n( 'reply', 'replies', post.comment_count)}} on "{{post.title}}"
```